# Why does real function being not locally one-to-one means that related complex function isn't also?

Tags: complex-analysis

Please, help me explain the last sentence in the proof. From where does it follow that Ψ is not locally one-to-one?

LEMMA. Let Ω ⊂ C be a CHD domain and let ρ be a real-valued continuous
function in Ω. Then the map Ψ(w) = w + ρ(w) is one-to-one in Ω ⇐⇒ Ψ is locally one-to-one.

PROOF. (⇒) Trivial. 
(⇐) Suppose the map Ψ(w) = w + ρ(w) is not one-to-one. Then, there are
distinct points w_1 = u_1 +iv_1, w_2 = u_2 +iv_2 ∈ Ω such that Ψ(w_1) = Ψ(w_2). Since ρ
is real-valued, we have that Im(Ψ(w_1)) = Im(w_1+ρ(w_1)) = Im(w_1) = v_1. Similarly,
Im(Ψ(w_2)) = v_2. Since Ψ(w_1) = Ψ(w_2), we have v_1 = v_2. Let’s say k = v_1 = v_2 for
a constant k ∈ R. Define Φ : \bar Ω ⊂ R → R by Φ(u) = u + ρ(u + ik). Because Ψ is
not one-to-one, we have
Φ(u_1) = u_1 + ρ(u_1 + k) = Re{Ψ(w_1)} = Re{Ψ(w_2)} = u_2 + ρ(u_2 + k) = Φ(u_2).
Thus, Φ is not a strictly monotonic function. Suppose u_0 is the point at which the
monotonicity of Φ changes. Because Φ maps into R, it cannot be locally one-to-one
in any neighborhood of u_0. Hence, Φ is not locally one-to-one, and Ψ is not locally
one-to-one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You never defined the term CHD domain.  And I think it'd help to tell people where this lemma appears: it is essentially Lemma 4.46 of https://math.byu.edu/~mdorff/docs/PaperBookHarmMapsChapter.pdf.